# SCANF function only records first letter pressed

Tags: keyboard, scanf, osdev

I am working on a simple OS in C++, and am trying to implement the keyboard without using interrupts (yes I'm being lazy-) however the char* returned by the function only has one letter (the first one pressed)
It uses a variable called MAX_16, which is simply 2^16
I'm making my own STDLIB and don't have access to most STDLIB functions.

```
char* scanf() {
    char* ret;
    for(int i = 0; i <= max_16; i++) {
        ret[i] = getkey();
        if(ret[i] == '\n') { return ret; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It collects keypresses using inb(0x60);

Answer (score 1):

`ret` is never initialized, so inside the loop, you are continually writing to garbage memory. Likely a fault is being triggered which causes the application to hang, causing no more input to be processed.

Comment: So simply add `char* ret = new char();`?